# Remove old connections from Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

In my remote desktop connection I had added to many machines. Right now I would like to remove some of them, but can not find an easy way to do this.

Here is an example:

[image]

Suppose I want to remove Machine 2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options - **manual:**

To remove entries from the Remote Desktop Connection Computer box in the Windows Remote Desktop Connection client, start Registry Editor, and then click the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default

Entries appear as MRUnumber, and are visible in the right pane.

To delete an entry, right-click it, and then click Delete.

**Automatic:**

Click the fix me button on the Microsoft site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312169